# AngularJs ui-router custom url

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

Ok, here is the problem. I have an app where user can signup as merchant and  can have their own store name and the url I looking for is:

```
http://localhost:8000/#/storename
```

This is getting conflict with default homepage subpages such as `contactus, aboutus`. Following is my implementation of `ui-router`.

```
.state('home', {
            url: '/', --> http://localhost:8000/#/ [work]
            templateUrl: 'views/main_home.html',
            resolve: loadSequence('flexSlider','wantCtrl'),
            css: 'assets/vendor/style.css'
          })
      .state('home.contact', {
            url: '/contact', --> http://localhost:8000/#/contact [not work]
            views: {
                    'homeView': {
                        templateUrl: 'partials/contact.html',

                    }
                },
            css: ['assets/vendor/style.css']
          })
           .state('store',{
            url: '/:storename',  -->  http://localhost:8000/#/myshop [work]
                templateUrl: 'views/main_store.html'        
            })
         .state('store.list', {
            url: '/lists', -->  http://localhost:8000/#/myshop/lists [work]
                views: {
                    'primView': {
                        templateUrl: 'views/store_home.html',
                    }
                }   
            })
```

Here the `http://localhost:8000/#/contact` are accessing the `store` template as if `contact` is a store name. Default whatever inherit `home.[anything]` should be under parent defined template. How can i resolve this issue?

There is dirty way of doing this, which is define new parent for each of the subpages, but that will be repetition of header and footer partial layout.

Comment: define

     .state('store',{
            url: '/:storename',  -->  http://localhost:8000/#/myshop [work]
                templateUrl: 'views/main_store.html'        
            })

 last. after all other routes

Comment: try after changing home.contact state to contact

Comment: @raj the page is load, but not load inside `views/main_home.html`, it loads directly on `index.html`

Comment: OK.. Then I guess u can try loading home page in /contact also and depending on URL populate ng include

Answer (score 0):

as far as i know angular follows top to bottom approach while dealing with routes. so define

```
       .state('store',{
        url: '/:storename',  -->  http://localhost:8000/#/myshop [work]
            templateUrl: 'views/main_store.html'        
        })
```

last after all other routes. In your case when angular reaches /:storename  itwill think that contact is a store name and load that page. to avoid it you need to keep it last

Comment: I made few changes, but still not work when I go specifically `/contact` page